# Using front and rear camera on the same activity android

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I know this question has been asked many times but i have no other option than asking this question again. I am using camera2 api to display both front and rear cameras on the same screen. I have created two texture views each with two camera instances. Even then I'm getting an exception.

This is my code for the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AndroidCameraApi";
    private TextureView textureView,textureView1;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }
    private String cameraId,cameraId1;
    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice,cameraDevice1;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions,cameraCaptureSessions1;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder,captureRequestBuilder1;
    private Size imageDimension,imageDimension1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler,mBackgroundHandler1;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread,mBackgroundThread1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_camera_api);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        textureView1 = (TextureView) findViewById(texture1);
        assert textureView != null;
        assert textureView1 != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        textureView1.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener1);

    }
    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            //open your camera here
            openCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener1 = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            //open your camera here
            openBackCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };


    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback1 = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice1 = camera;
            createCameraPreview1();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice1.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice1.close();
            cameraDevice1 = null;
        }
    };


    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void startBackgroundThread1() {
        mBackgroundThread1 = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread1.start();
        mBackgroundHandler1 = new Handler(mBackgroundThread1.getLooper());
    }
    protected void stopBackgroundThread1() {
        mBackgroundThread1.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread1.join();
            mBackgroundThread1 = null;
            mBackgroundHandler1 = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void createCameraPreview1() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture1 = textureView1.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture1 != null;
            texture1.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension1.getWidth(), imageDimension1.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture1);
            captureRequestBuilder1 = cameraDevice1.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder1.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice1.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions1 = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview1();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }

    private void openBackCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId1 = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId1);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension1 = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId1, stateCallback1, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }


    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void updatePreview1() {
        if(null == cameraDevice1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder1.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions1.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder1.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler1);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
        startBackgroundThread1();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }

        if (textureView1.isAvailable()) {
            openBackCamera();
        } else {
            textureView1.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener1);
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        //closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        stopBackgroundThread1();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Code for layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Exception i am getting is as below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.close()' on a null object reference
```

I am getting exception on this line:

```
  cameraDevice1.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which of the cameraDevice1.close() calls fails? Did you ever get an onOpened call for that camera?

There's no guarantee that a given Android device can have multiple cameras open at once; the only way to know is to try, and if it can't be done, the second camera will not fire onOpened, it'll fire onError with error code TOO_MANY_CAMERAS_IN_USE.

So if that's happening here, then you'll get onError without onOpened, and your cameraDevice1 will never have been set.

Comment: Yes there is no onOpened call for the second camera. So device must not be having multiple cameras open at once as you said. But is there any solution for this??

Comment: Unfortunately no - this is generally a hardware limitation; the front and back cameras share processing hardware, and there's not enough of it to run both at once.  (Sometimes there's enough to run one camera at very low resolution or with other limited features, but this isn't something the API can tell you - but the built-in camera app may be able to use custom interfaces for that).